# python selenium remote webdriver safari driver

Tags: python, selenium, safari, webdriver

I have this java-code for safari with RemoteWebDriver (I need it as I test in different systems in several browsers like safari, ff, ie, chrome... using Selenium 2):

```
Selenium sel = new DefaultSelenium(host, 4444, "*safari", baseURL);
CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(sel);
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
WebDriver browser = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, dc);
```

I know that in Python first and last lines will be:

```
self.selenium = selenium(host, 4444, "*safariproxy", baseURL)
...
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities = dc, command_executor = executor)
```

But still can't rewrite middle java-code to Python. Can anybody help me?

May be there is another way to create webdriver remote connection with safari in Python? I need webdriver, not Selenium 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no official support for Safari with Web Driver. You'd have to use Selenium 1/RC.

Answer (score 3):

Once the Safari driver is correctly installed(http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver) you should be able to do the following to get this working (I have managed to get it working on 2.24.1):

```
dc = {‘browserName’: ‘safari’}
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=dc)
```

Comment: too bad this requires running the server JAR when you don't have to do that from Java with the SafariDriver() local binding.